# Согласно ЧЕГО или согласно ЧЕМУ?

Tags: согласование

Как правильно:
*Произвести расчет согласно показа**ний** приборов учета или согласно показа**ниям**?*

Answer (score 1):

**согласно**
чему (*устар*. чего) и с чем.

1. ***чему*** (на основании чего-либо).
   Согласно предписанию. Согласно уставу.
   *Жениховой родне, согласно уговору, поднесли по три рюмки водки* (Шолохов).
2. ***с чем*** (в соответствии с чем-либо).
   Согласно с требованиями морали.
   [Она] *нередко изменяет свои распоряжения согласно с его советами* (Салтыков-Щедрин).
   Д.Э. Розенталь. Пунктуация и управление в русском языке

*Предлог **согласно** в современном русском языке требует дательного падежа, правильно: **согласно чему.***
[**Грамота.ру. Согласно**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_64)

**Произвести расчёт согласно показаниям приборов учёта.**

Comment: *«согласно с его советам»* — имеет место несогласованность по падежам. *«согласно с (чем?)»* находится в творительном падеже, а *«советам»* — в дательном. Что это было у Михаила Евграфовича — описка в рукописи или умышленное искажение? И если искажение, то чем обусловленное?

Comment: Вопрос стоял о выборе родительного или дательного падежа. В _этой_ конструкции правилен _только_ дательный: чему?

Comment: @slava1947 Спасибо за правку, я не успела подкорректировать — не сразу заметила.

Comment: Вопрос очень сложный: понять само слово "согласно" (со+глас); разницу "основание" и "основа"; Дательный падеж с его шестью делениями и Родительный падеж с его шестью делениями... я бы мог две страницы написать и всё по полочкам разложить. Нельзя запрещать Родительный падеж с "согласно показаний" - ведь это правильно. До 19в. использовали, использовали, но вмешался Розенталь и теперь нельзя использовать - матрица в действии.